# How to determine is the customer from outside the country?

Tags: javascript, magento, module, popup, customization

I'm wondering how can i check if the customer is from outside the country before is logged in?
I would like to display a popup message depending on it.

Comment: put relevant code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options :

- Use [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) (but he can refuse it) and resolve his GPS coordinates
- Get his location by his IP address with a service like [IP2Location](https://github.com/ip2location-nodejs/IP2Location)